# Actualizar varias tablas al mismo tiempo en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo varios modelos, asociados respectivamente a cada tabla en postgresql, necesito guardar todas las modificaciones al mismo tiempo, pero si falla alguna creación que no guarde ninguna.

Tengo los modelos `Partido, Jugador, Arbitro`

Intenté algo como esto:

```
partido = Partido.create({campo: campo, fecha: fecha})
Jugador.create({partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre1, numero: numero1}, {partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre2, numero: numero2}) if partido
Arbitro.create({partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre}) if partido
```

Si en un caso hipotético falla crear el registro de Arbitro, no me sirve que guarde los jugadores  ni el partido, o falla crear cualquier de los jugadores, tampoco me sirve que guarde el partido y los arbitros, o si fallan los arbitros y los jugadores pero crea el partido tampoco me sirve, porque se crearía inconsistencia en los datos en todos estos casos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveRecord.transaction` existe justo para esos casos, donde necesitas que se guarde todo o no se guarde nada; solo debes proporcionar como bloque las operaciones que deseas realizar y, si alguna de ellas tiene error (i.e. arroja una excepción), se hará un `ROLLBACK`:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  partido = Partido.create!({campo: campo, fecha: fecha})

  Jugador.create!({partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre1, numero: numero1}, {partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre2, numero: numero2})
  Arbitro.create!({partido_id: partido.id, nombre: nombre})
end
```

Es importante notar que cambié los métodos `create` por `create!`, ya que el primero no arroja una excepción si encuentra un error, mientras que el segundo sí lo hace.